# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location error in destructor

Tags: pointers, c++14, allegro5

I have a class that is meant to load image files to bitmaps and keep references to those bitmaps. I want to deallocate these resources at some point later like just before shutting the application down.

So my class (is a singleton) designed like:

```
class ImageManager
{
public:
   static ImageManager &getInstance();
   ImageManager(ImageManager const&) = delete;
   void operator=(ImageManager const&) = delete;
   void loagImage(char *location);
   ~ImageManager();
private:
   ImageManager();
   ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image = nullptr;
}
```

There's nothing much in the constructor really. Just loads an add-on related to handling bitmaps. No raw pointers are created.

The `loadImage()` is implemented as below:

```
void ImageManager::loadImage(char *location)
{
    if(!location)
    {
       throw std::invalid_argument("Location cannot be null.");
    }
    image = al_load_bitmap(location);
}
```

The destructor is defined like

```
ImageManager::~ImageManager()
{
   if(image)
   {
       al_destroy_bitmap(image); // Here I get the access violation exception.
   }
}
```

The way this class is used in the `main.cpp` is like:

```
int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    ImageManager &imgManager = ImageManager::getInstance();
    imgManager.loadImage("valid/location");

    return 0;
}
```

If I call the `al_destroy_bitmap()` in the same function that loads the bitmap, there's no error. It only happens when I try to call it in the destructor.

I'm on Windows 10 using VS17. I saw a number of questions on the same topic but I could not figure out the error using the answers there. I will also link to the two allegro methods here in case you need:

1. [al_load_bitmap()](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/graphics.html#al_load_bitmap)
2. [al_destroy_bitmap()](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/graphics.html#al_destroy_bitmap)

EDIT:

My `getInstance()` method is:

```
ImageManager &ImageManager::getInstance()
{
    static ImageManager instance;
    return instance;
}
```

EDIT 2:

Exact error is `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDF1.`

Comment: what does your getInstance look like?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly destroy the `imgManager` instance before `return 0`? The bitmap may already be destroyed before `ImageManager::~ImageManager` is called.

Comment: @Anders Added the `getInstance()` method.

Comment: @J.R. Tried explicitly calling the destructor, same error... I think you are right in that the bitmap is already deallocated, just can't figure out where...

Comment: How do you call the destructor? Another test would be to set `image` to `nullptr` in `ImageManager::~ImageManager`...

Comment: Changing `instance` to a pointer, having `getInstance` create an instance, and adding an explicit 'destroyInstance` call to delete the `instance` before `return 0` may fix the problem because you know longer have a destruction/deallocation sequence that is out of your control after exiting `main`.

Comment: @J.R. I did as you advised and it's working now. Feel free to post an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: i think you have other problems in your code, the getInstance method looks fine, i would advise to skip having it as a singleton as singleton can cause a problem since singletons are considered an anti pattern by most (although in some special cases you need them)

Comment: singletons are like a global variable, so you have less control over them

Comment: @Anders Thanks, I agree with you. I do intend to change this into a normal class, though there's one other class, I kind of need to keep a singleton (changing this just brings in other complexities). So, the advice here is still useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allegro 5 doesn't play nice with globals like singletons.

Things to remember :

1) Global objects or global calls to static initialization happen before `al_init` is called. This means calls to allegro functions inside their constructors will fail.

2) Global statics outlive main and atexit. This means their destructors will run after allegro is typically shutdown. [al_install_system](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/system.html#al_install_system) hooks atexit for shutting down it's library unless you specifically tell it not to. This means calls to allegro functions like `al_destroy_bitmap` will fail and segfault if you're lucky.

You'll have to explictly 'shutdown' your ImageManager instance, before atexit and main exits OR before you call [al_uninstall_system](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/system.html#al_uninstall_system).

Answer (score 0):

Changing `instance` to a pointer, having `getInstance` create an instance, and adding an explicit `destroyInstance` call to delete the instance before `return 0` may fix the problem because you no longer have a destruction/deallocation sequence that is out of your control after exiting main.